# Changing priority of a subscriber coming from a vendor's bundle

Tags: symfony, symfony4, event-listener

To set **some context**, I'm working on a Symfony 4.4 API, which use a vendor named [`EkinoNewRelicBundle`](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoNewRelicBundle) to communicate data to the New Relic API.
This vendor uses a subscriber named [`RequestListener`](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoNewRelicBundle/blob/master/Listener/RequestListener.php) to subscribe on the `kernel.request` event of Symonfy to define data to send to the New Relic API.

I've got **an issue** in a specific case, when there is an authentication issue resulting in a 498, another subscriber from the `SecurityBundle` throw an exception, stopping the request processing.
Unfortunately, a method of the `EkinoNewRelicBundle`  subscriber, named [`setTransactionName`](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoNewRelicBundle/blob/aa36288b98e56b082b08dd0602384ca47b473ea5/Listener/RequestListener.php#L56), has a lower priority than the SecurityBundle subscriber, resulting in data not properly set by Ekino as the process is stop.

By editing by hand the vendor, I found that a priority `10` on the `setTransactionName` would be enough to be executed before the `SecurityBundle`.

I'm looking for a way to edit the priority of the `RequestListener` priority at runtime.
So far, **I've tried** to :

- [**override** the configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles/override.html), but as the priority is defined in a public static method from a class and seems to be loaded directly in the EventDispatcher, therefore it's no configuration to override ;
- [use a **compiler pass**](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to manipulate the definition, but same as above, there is no definition to edit as it seems to be loaded directly in the EventDispatcher ;
- **extend** the Ekino subscriber to edit the priority, disabling the listner from the Ekino's configuration, but this results in configuration issue of my newly define subscriber as it can't be autowired.

Isn't there an easy way to change a priority of a subscribed event in a vendor's subscriber?

The maintener did talk about this seven years ago, when the configuration was still accessible with the compiler pass [in this EkinoNewRelicBundle issue](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoNewRelicBundle/issues/93#issuecomment-126696156).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [How to Override any Part of a Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/bundles/override.html#services-configuration) Symfony Documentation.

> If you want to modify the services created by a bundle, you can use
> [service decoration](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/service_container/service_decoration.html).

As the `Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener` is a service that is registered in the [configs](https://github.com/ekino/EkinoNewRelicBundle/blob/2.3.0/Resources/config/http_listener.xml) and autoconfigured by Symfony, you can create a decorator and add a custom `getSubscribedEvents()` method to override the priorities.

### **Create the Decorator**

```
// /src/Decorator/EkinoRequestListenerDecorator.php

namespace App\Decorator;

use Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\KernelRequestEvent;
use Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class EkinoRequestListenerDecorator implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    /** 
     * @var RequestListener
     */
    private $decorated;

    public function __construct(RequestListener $decorated)
    {
        $this->decorated = $decorated;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
                ['setApplicationName', 255],
                ['setIgnoreTransaction', 31],
                ['setTransactionName', 10],
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function setApplicationName(KernelRequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $this->decorated->setApplicationName($event);
    }

    public function setIgnoreTransaction(KernelRequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $this->decorated->setIgnoreTransaction($event);
    }

    public function setTransactionName(KernelRequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $this->decorated->setTransactionName($event);
    }
}
```

### **Configure the Decorator**

> The decorates option tells the container that the `App\Decorator\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator`
> service replaces the `Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener` service.

> This configuration replaces `Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener` with a new one, but keeps a
> reference of the old one as `App\Decorator\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator.inner`

```
# /config/services.yaml

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # ...

    App\Decorator\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator:
        decorates: Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener
        arguments: ['@App\Decorator\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator.inner']
```

### **Debug the event dispatcher**

```
php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request
```

**Resulting `kernel.request` Event Dispatcher**

Before

```
Registered Listeners for "kernel.request" Event
===============================================

 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                                                Priority  
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  #3      Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener::setApplicationName()                                     255       
  #8      Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener::setIgnoreTransaction()                                   31            
  #21     Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener::setTransactionName()                                     -10       
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

After

```
Registered Listeners for "kernel.request" Event
===============================================

 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- 
  Order   Callable                                                                                                Priority  
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------     
  #3      App\Decorator\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator::setApplicationName()                                       255       
  #8      App\Decorator\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator::setIgnoreTransaction()                                     31
  #13     App\Decorator\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator::setTransactionName()                                       10        
 ------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
```

**Resulting Container Event Listeners**

```
        $instance->addListener('kernel.request', [0 => function () {
            return ($this->privates['App\\Decorator\\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator'] ?? $this->getEkinoRequestListenerDecoratorService());
        }, 1 => 'setApplicationName'], 255);
        $instance->addListener('kernel.request', [0 => function () {
            return ($this->privates['App\\Decorator\\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator'] ?? $this->getEkinoRequestListenerDecoratorService());
        }, 1 => 'setIgnoreTransaction'], 31);
        $instance->addListener('kernel.request', [0 => function () {
            return ($this->privates['App\\Decorator\\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator'] ?? $this->getEkinoRequestListenerDecoratorService());
        }, 1 => 'setTransactionName'], 10);


//...

    protected function getEkinoRequestListenerDecoratorService()
    {
        return $this->privates['App\\Decorator\\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator'] = new \App\Decorator\EkinoRequestListenerDecorator(new \Ekino\NewRelicBundle\Listener\RequestListener(($this->privates['Ekino\\NewRelicBundle\\NewRelic\\Config'] ?? $this->getConfigService()), ($this->privates['Ekino\\NewRelicBundle\\NewRelic\\BlackholeInteractor'] ?? ($this->privates['Ekino\\NewRelicBundle\\NewRelic\\BlackholeInteractor'] = new \Ekino\NewRelicBundle\NewRelic\BlackholeInteractor())), [], [], new \Ekino\NewRelicBundle\TransactionNamingStrategy\RouteNamingStrategy()));
    }
```

Comment: I had troubles understanding and exploiting decoration, your answer and links within make it clear, thanks.

Following the examples, I've added the decorator and the configuration and I did have the new decorator listener with the priority 10 in the callable order. The decorator did receive the decorated listener in its constructor, allowing to call the original listener.

But sadly, the old listener is still here, alongside the decoration. As I understand the Service Decoration Symfony documentation, the decoration should act as a replacement, with no traces of the original?

Comment: @b4v Correct, the decorated service replaces the original. My answer includes the actual testing with the `debug:event-dispatcher kernel.request`, The original service is injected into the decorated service but should be removed from the `event-dispatcher`. Check your configs to ensure your attempts to manually override the subscriber are not adding it again. In my tests there were no references in the event-dispatcher for the original listeners.

Comment: @b4v Also be sure you are putting the decorates declaration BELOW the default services configuration that includes `resource:`, so that it replaces any services that are auto-discovered

Comment: Perfect, I did mistakenly put the decoration in the beginning of my configuration. Now the service is well replaced, and I did not have the double listener in the order. Many thanks for your help and quality of your answer.